# Login to facebook does not work if facebook app is installed on emulator - Android 4.3

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have been banging my head on this problem for a while now. I know there are other posts of a similar fashion but I cant seem to get anything to work. I have the issue where if the Facebook app is on the emulator it will not login properly.

What happens is when a user will hit the login button a small dialog will pop up and ask them if the app can get these things(permissions) from them. You hit OK and it brings you back and nothing is changed....

I look at my LOGCAT and see that it repeatedly says: Logged Out (two times) every time you hit the button.

Logging in works if FB is not installed on the emulator.

Here is my code:

FBInit - Fragment Activity Handler:

```
public class FBInit extends FragmentActivity {

private FBInitFragment fbInitFrag;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fbinit);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        fbInitFrag = new FBInitFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fbInitFrag).commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        fbInitFrag = (FBInitFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }

    findViewById(R.id.fb_init_next).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result", 1);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.fb_init_back).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result", 1);
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fbinit, menu);
    return true;
}



}
```

FBInitFragment :

```
public class FBInitFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "FBInitFragment";

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fbinit, container, false);

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);

    return view;
}

private final Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```

Please advise!!

Thanks

Andy

Comment: If you're being transitioned to a closed state, that usually means an error occurred, try printing out the exception passed into the onSessionStateChange method. Likely candidate for error is not having your key hash setup properly in your app settings on Facebook.

Comment: Hey I did what you advised, and I get this:

09-12 21:06:25.865: I/System.out(1403): com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException: remote_app_id does not match stored id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means your key hashes are incorrectly set in your app settings.

Please see this section on getting your key hashes and setting them correctly: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/#create-app